# How to link GLX?

Tags: c++, linux, linker, static-linking, glx

I'm trying to find the compiler flag for linking GLX on a Linux based system. So far, I have (in qt Creator):

```
unix:LIBS += -lglx -lX11 -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL -lXext -L/usr/X11R6/lib
```

But, that still gives me `glxChooseVisual was not declared in this scope`, thus preventing my code from compiling.

Comment: You're not including whatever header glxChooseVisual is in. This has nothing to do with the linker.

Comment: According to the OpenGL wiki from which I've been using as a tutorial for X-Server development (and according to my auto-completion, which only shows functions for the libraries I've included), I have included the right file.

Comment: Namespaces don't exist in C libraries...

Comment: __1.__ You tagged it C++ and I don't know every library under the sun (I even googled for this one but no luck) __2.__ The error message clearly tells you it can't find the declaration of `glxChooseVisual`. Maybe you're missing a define or something, only looking at the header will help here

Comment: It was just a stupid misnomer on my part. Regardless, I appreciate you taking the time to help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When defining a `glX` function, the 'X' *must* be capitalized. That was my fault for not seeing that. Consider this problem solved.